# Host multiple meteor application on DigitalOcean

Tags: node.js, meteor, nginx, reverse-proxy, digital-ocean

I need to run two meteor applications at the same Digital Ocean droplet. Following [this tutorial](http://odlaner.com/host-multiple-meteor-and-ghost-instances-on-digitalocean/) I successfully get both apps to work on my-domain.com:3000 and my-domain-1.com:3001, but I can't get reversing proxy using Nginx done. Following the tutorial I came up with the following:

First app configuration file:

```js
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name http://saveting.com;

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }
}
```

Second app configuration:

```js
server {
 listen 80;
 server_name http://downloadinstagramvideo.com;

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 }
}
```

**EDIT1 :**

The problem was that nginx has to be restarted before implementing changes. Works after using:

```
sudo service nginx start
```

Comment: Richard Smith has the answer below. I'd also recommend adding another line to the `location /` block: `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;`

Comment: Your configuration may be different than what I'm used to on my dev machine, but just in case... usually port 3001 is used by meteor for mongo (I believe), I use 3002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `server_name` directive should not include the scheme name, use:

```
server_name saveting.com;
```

and

```
server_name downloadinstagramvideo.com;
```